# Calculate cylindrical billboard

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl, shader

I'm having trouble with how to calculate cylindrical billboard in the vertex shader.

This is how I do with spherical:

```
vec3 sphericalVertex = centerPos +
    cameraRightVector * xOffset * billboardSize +
    cameraUpVector * yOffset * billboardSize;
```

How do I change the calculations?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate here?

Comment: I solved it. The cameraUpVector should be a constant, i.e. vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0).